# Display all values from Z3 model (Python)

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

When I want to get the values of all variables in an SMT2 instance, I use the command `(set-option :auto-config false)`. In Z3py, setting this option doesn't work - the model doesn't display variables that I define but do not use in any constraints. If I ask for the values of these variables, I get `None`. I have tried these options but none of them produce the result that I want:

```
set_option('model_evaluator.completion', True)
set_option('smt.auto-config', False)
set_option('auto-config', False)
```

What should I do to get concrete values for these variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `auto-config` option does not tell Z3 to print or omit parts of models; it just enables or disables automatic configuration of the solver (based on static formula features).

When a variable is not assigned a value in a model, it is simply irrelevant, i.e., you can make up any value for it, and it will still be a correct model. Depending on which solvers/tactics you use, the option `model_evaluator.completion` may solve that problem, but the safest way is to enable model completion at the time of model evaluation, i.e., use the [eval(..)](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3py_1_1_model_ref.html#a1a418b495787876acaf6b5392ea617c6) function with `model_completion=True`